# AVPlayer: Unable to stream-play .mp4 & .mpg files

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I've been trying to do video streaming and haven't resolved the KVO issue. I saw an alternate way via `prepareForSegue` as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! AVPlayerViewController
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov")
    destination.player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
}
```

This works (iOS 9: if you bypass the App Transport Security).

So I substituted the following URL (.mp4):

```
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/videos/video1.mp4
```

What I got was a blank screen. As if it was trying to load and perhaps timed out.

Then I tried a .mpg file of the URL:

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/6b8388b7-14c6-431a-a795-2b33f9d47081/tfss-2d72ec5d-8a8d-467b-b799-20c06be52ddb-ngc4261_1.mpg
```

Of which I got this:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why can't I play the .mp4 file? -- Is it due to size?
   Do I need to do a KVO or NSNotification observation here?
2. Why can't I play the .mpg file? -- Is it due to wrong format?

Comment: did you find an answer to this as i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

since adding that comment i have just realised the problem i had, maybe its the same. Did you change the server domain in the plist file when changing to a completely different video stored on a different domain?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>myDomain.co.uk</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

the 'myDomain.co.uk' needs to change to the where the video is kept, server address

Comment: No... I didn't go that route for the video.

Comment: No... I didn't go that route for the video.  I eventually load the video asset via '...asset?.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(...' and played the video.  Where asset = AVAsset(URL: url).   I stayed away from KVO, being so 'brittle'.